# how do I add and commit a png screenshot image to a local repo?

Tags: git, image, github, png, screenshot

I see repos in github that just have a screenshot added. Not a screenshot inside an md file, the png is it's own file in the repo. I want to know how to get the screenshot png into the local repo and commit it to be pushed to github without using the gui.

Answer (score 1):

Presuming that "screenshot" here refers to a .png file. I am pretty sure you can add the png in the directory you want to and then stage-->commit-->push. AFAIK this should work.

Answer (score -2):

You should get screenshot via some tool (press "PrtScn" button for Monitor screenshot >> open paint >> paste >> save as 'screenshot.jpg')

1. copy this file in your Git repo
2. add filr "git add screenshot.jpg"
3. commit "git commit"
4. push "git push"
5. DONE :)

Comment: It does not copy into the repo. Even using the gui .

Comment: run "git status" and check if file appear as 'new file' or 'modified' file. if file is listed, it should definitely get added. If not listed, open your 'gitignore' file and check if same format of files is mentioned there to ignore.